# Dynamic IF statement that updates once condition met

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas

I'm struggling to work out how to forecast inventory for my ecommerce store.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1X4pdpA-6c4bo-H6NptIU-A2KglbUV61LrR97bhmdrPc/edit?usp=sharing

Essentially, I need the conditions of my IF statement to update once the condition has been met. You can see that in cell C5 (highlighted yellow) that's where the first re order happens of 2000 units. Then, I want the formula to use the next re order value of 3000 going forward in cell C6. I've tried lookups but haven't been able to come up with anything.

I'm not sure if this is actually possible without some background code. As it's almost like a FOR loop scenario.

Here's the workbook.

I would appreciate any help, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's exactly what you expect to have? The amount remaining until the next re-order?
You can try this approach that calculates how much it's until the next thousand:

> =1000-MOD(SUM($B$2:B2),1000)

Is this?, If not, explain it a little further ;)

---

EDIT:

You can try to do this with Match and Index. I'm attaching here a picture of your document with some extra steps to understand the final formula:
Col H finds the total sum until each row

> =SUM($B$2:B2)

Col I matches that Sum with column F. Since I've added that final "1" in the formula it will find the nearest lower value (that's why I added 0 in F1).

> '=match(H2,F:F,1)

Col J: Having that "position" with "Match" we can now go to F2:F and find which is the next value (note that in Match I used F:F, and now  F1:F so I find the next one)

> '=INDEX($F$2:F,I2)

Col K: And now you just need to substract the total sum from that value

> '=J2-H2

Col L: If you want to have a formula that accomplishes all that in just one cell you can use this:

> =index($F$2:$F,match(sum($B$2:B2),F:F,1))-sum($B$2:B2)

**Does this solve the issue??** You can modify and extend the re-order column all you want and it will find between which values the sum is and the difference to the upper one

[image: unraveling the formula]

RE-EDIT: Understanding now that the re-orders were accumulative, I've created a G column with the accumulative sums, and a new formula in O that matches the corresponding sum with that column. I've left the earlier steps in case it's useful for someone else

> =Index(G:G,match(sum($B$2:B2),G:G,1)+1)-sum($B$2:B2)

[image: New option]

Comment: So in cell C5 the formula adds F3 which is 2000 units. The next time I have to re order based on that 2000 units (which is cell C9) I would like to add 3000 units as in cell F4, and so on, and so on. Does that make sense? So every time I reorder I want the values to increase. Not just be a standard 2000 units each time. This will allow me to change the values in the F columns to monitor cashflow etc.

Comment: Look at the Edit in this answer ;)
You can just jump to the end of the answer, I tried to explain which was the logic of my process (and you have it in your spreadsheet too!)

Comment: Appreciate the effort but it's not quite doing what I need. I've written a manual formula in the spreadsheet of how I need it to work.

Comment: Hello! Now I understand, I haven't got earlier that they were accumulative!
I've added a G column with the accumulative sum, and created a new formula in column O!

Comment: I've added an edit to this answer ;)

Comment: omg I think you've done it! I cannot thank you enough sir. Thank you so much. I've been stuck on this for days!

Comment: Great! I'm glad it works and it's useful!